# How to set position dynamically in mongoose push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push some data to a nested array. My data is like:

```
{a:[{x:[{'y':'z'}]}]}
```

I am trying to push values into x array. I tried this way, it works=>

```
{ "$push": { "a.0.x": data}}
```

But, is there a way where I can pass the value `0` dynamically. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
{ $push: { "a.$.x": {
    $each: [data], 
    $position: 1 
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a mongoose way. But, here is a way I did it by passing index to the object property.

```js
var i = "1";
var obj = { ["prop"+i+"Name"]: "response" };
console.log(obj);
```